# Examples of realization of functors between quite diverse categories?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, category-theory

What examples contemporary math provide for the realization of functors between quite diverse categories, e.g. between category of matrices and category of graphs?

This question is more category specific generalization of 
[Graph valued function, mapping from reals to graph (maybe about realization of functors)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159371/graph-valued-function-mapping-from-reals-to-graph-maybe-about-realization-of-f) that provides some motivation for this question.